# Being safe in multiple users on Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

So its been a while since I actually had to allow multiple users access to my server via Remote Desktop. Usually it has sufficed to just give them FTP but in this case the user in question needs the ability to start + stop certain applications.

I want to know I am doing this in a 'safe manner' - as in that I am not taking risks by giving a user too many permissions. I guess that Power User is the most appropriate group, but I just want input here first?

Comment: Power User was deprecated after XP/2003. I'm really not even sure that it still does anything.

Comment: Ah, my mistake I suppose you could say then. I took it for granted the group was still valid/usable since it is present. I'm more used to 2003/2008R2 and I believe it did give elevated privileges on those OS'.

Comment: It still *may*, it's just been marked as deprecated by Microsoft since Vista/2008 came out. When Microsoft deprecates something, it may still be present and function, but you should find an alternative solution as it may be removed from a future OS without warning and then you don't have an upgrade path.

Comment: This isn't really something that can be easily answered here.  You have to take into account your office policies/politics as well as risk allowed.  Some people wouldn't mind giving the person domain admin rights, others might want them to be locked down on RDP to the point that they can only login and run a single app.  What might be "safe" for a 3 person auto repair shop may not be for a power plant.

Comment: Standard users should be able to launch and run applications on the server without any specific tweaking being necessary.